# If using "using" is it important to use var type

Tags: c#

Are the following equivalent?
Is it important to use `var` type in certain circumstances?

Currently using this:

```
static int ReturnIDfromDb(string sqlString, string outputParam) {
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var comm = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this not more specific?

```
static int ReturnIDfromDb(string sqlString, string outputParam) {
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you know they're the same, which one will you use? Most dev's I've worked with prefer to use `var` as its less typing. Others prefer fully qualified especially when declaring numbers, in order to know the boundary/limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the compiler it is the same. Seriously. `var` turns into hardcoded.

But still, there are corcumstances where you HAVE to use var, because you DO NOT KNOW THE TYPE.

`IQueryable` (LINQ) allows you to project:

.....

```
.Select (x=> new { Name = x.Name; }).ToArray();
```

In this case you get an array of - anonymous types, so...

it has to be

var resultarray

because you CAN NOT name the type at this point.

But `var` is a COMPILER ONLY thing. Code convention of Resharper says: use var, not type. I tend to agree these days.

After the compiler it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

If your explicitly defining the type of object the variable is going to contain, in this case by using the new keyword on the classname, then you can use `var` simply as a shortcut instead of having to type the class name twice.  There isn't any technical difference.

Using `var` is easier to type and to read, for example:

```
Dictionary<int, MyLongNamedObject> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyLongNamedObject>();
```

or

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyLongNamedObject>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are equivalent.

`var` is always equivalent (though shorter) than actually using the compile-time type of the expression.

However, when using anonymous types, you need to use `var`, since there is no specific named type that you can write yourself.

Comment: +1 so in some circumstances I need to use `var` but in _this_ context I'm ok using either?

Answer (score 1):

The `var` keyword is not itself a 'type'. `var` asks the compiler to automatically infer the type for you. There is no difference..

The use of the `var` keyword comes down to personal or team preference. Try to remain consistent and try to use it only where, at a glance, the type can be inferred by the human brain.

E.g:

```
// bad
var customers = GetCustomers();

// good
var customers = GetListOfCustomers();
```

The above may be personal preference also given that intellisense can be a life saver.. but it helps when reviewing code.

It's also useful for shortening declarations of nested generic types (e.g, a dictionary where the value is also a dictionary containing a list of strings).

Answer (score 1):

### Those codes are totaly equivalent.

`var` is much more useful when **you don't know**  or **don't need to know about the type** cases.

Let's say we have `Car` class and `Cleaners` property. When we wrote code like this;

```
Car c = new Car();
var cleaner = c.Cleaners;
```

**We don't need to know** type of `cleaner` is `IEnumerable<Cleaner>` or `BindingList<Cleaner>` or whatever. If we use `IEnumerable<Cleaner>` or `BindingList<Cleaner>` in this case, this could be a problem. Because the returning type could be one of these types. Using `var` on this case, we don't care what the type of `cleaner`.

Comment: When iterating over it.. this may be so.. but if your need is to use something specific (as a quick example, the `ForEach` method of `List<T>`) then you would want to explicitly type it as such. This makes reviewing the code easier. Also, a non-plural version of a collection of objects makes my eyes bleed!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Of course, if your returning type is a specific type, some cases, using `var` may cause some memory/type problems.

Answer (score 1):

I try to specify a class or interface that reflects what the code actually requires.  This gives me confidence that future alterations won't break other code.

I'd use:

```
static int ReturnIDfromDb(string sqlString, string outputParam) {
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
    using(DbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(DbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        comm.CommandText = sqlString;
        ...
    }
}
```

If I later decide to change from a `SqlConnection` to an `OracleConnection`, I have confidence that any use of the `conn` or `comm` variables will not require modification.

Note that this may not always be appropriate if you require unique features of the concrete `~Connection` or `~Command` classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely equivalent, i dont think  that using var, if you can, ever makes a difference.

You do however sometimes have to use var.